# How can I print the palindrome words in a sentence? If I input "Madam Arora teaches math", it should print "Madam Arora"

Tags: java, loops, stack, queue, palindrome

```java
class Palindrome { 
      
    // Function to check if a word is 
    // palindrome 
    static boolean checkPalin(String word) 
    { 
        int n = word.length(); 
        word = word.toLowerCase(); 
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++,n--) 
           if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(n - 1)) 
              return false;        
        return true; 
    } 
      
    // Function to count palindrome words 
    static int countPalin(String str) 
    {         
        // to check last word for palindrome 
        str = str + " "; 
          
        // to store each word 
        String word = ""; 
        int count = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
        { 
            char ch = str.charAt(i); 
              
            // extracting each word 
            if (ch != ' ') 
                word = word + ch; 
            else { 
                if (checkPalin(word)) 
                    count++; 
                word = ""; 
            } 
        } 
          
        return count; 
    } 
      
    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println(countPalin("Madam "
                  + "Arora teaches malayalam")); 
                    
        System.out.println(countPalin("Nitin "
                        + "speaks malayalam")); 
    }
}
```

I only know how to count the number. How can I run through a loop and check every word if it is a palindrome? Can you help me with a method that checks a word and a method that checks a sentence if there are palindrome words? I must use Stacks and Queues. I have done the push, add, remove, dequeue, but I can't check if the input is a sentence.

Comment: why not split the input by space and pass each element of this array to your method that checks if its a palindrome. It should handle both words & sentences

Comment: so i’ll use the split() method then i’ll use the method that checks if it is a palindrome?

Comment: yes, for each word you got after split

Comment: What alternative solution can i use except for the split method?

Comment: i have an idea where the loop would check the word then stop by a whitespace then continue on the next word until it reaches the last index. I converted the input string to a char array. Please help 

Comment: what you have suggested is just an alternate to split() method. What is the issue/error you are facing

Comment: yes i get the concept but i can’t put it into code, please help me with the part where the loop would check the word then stop by a whitespace then continue on the next word until it reaches the last index.

Comment: code that you have shared seems to reflect the flow/logic you want to implement. The only issue i can spot is that it would not check the last word of the sentence as loop gets terminated and checkPalin() never gets invoked

Comment: invoke checkPalin() method once again after flow exits the loop and update count corresspondingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change only this part

```
if (checkPalin(word)) 
{ 
     OutPut =  OutPut + word;
 }
```

after for loop return OutPut.

Answer (score 0):

```
// C# program to count number of 
// palindrome words in a sentence 
using System; 

class Palindrome 
{ 

// Function to check if a word is 
// palindrome 
public static bool checkPalin(string word) 
{ 
    int n = word.Length; 
    word = word.ToLower(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++,n--) 
    { 
    if (word[i] != word[n - 1]) 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
    } 
    return true; 
} 

// Function to count palindrome words 
public static int countPalin(string str) 
{ 
    // to check last word for palindrome 
    str = str + " "; 

    // to store each word 
    string word = ""; 
    string Print_Result = "";
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) 
    { 
        char ch = str[i]; 

        // extracting each word 
        if (ch != ' ') 
        { 
            word = word + ch; 
        } 
        else
        { 
            if (checkPalin(word)) 
            { 
                if (Print_Result == "")
                {
                    Print_Result =  word;
                }else
                {
                    Print_Result = Print_Result + word;
                } 
                 
            } 
            word = ""; 
        } 
    } 

    return Print_Result; 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(countPalin("Madam " + 
            "Arora teaches math")); 

} 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw that on geeksforgeeks

Comment: you have to just store palindrome word instead of count by changing above code Print_Result =  word;

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a method to return a list of palindrome words after splitting the input string with `String.split`.

It is convenient to use Java 8 Stream API for such tasks (`filter` and `collect`):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Palindrome {
// ...

    public static List<String> findPalindromes(String str) {
        if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+")) // split into "words" separated with whitespaces
                     .filter(Palindrome::checkPalin) // keep the palindrome words
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());  // get the list from stream
    }

    // then countPalin() may be refactored as
    public static countPalin(String str) {
        return findPalindromes(str).size();
    }
}
```

Test

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] data = { null, "", "None",
                "Madam Arora teaches malayalam",
                "Nitin speaks malayalam"
    };

    for (String str : data) {
        List<String> palindromes = findPalindromes(str);
        if (palindromes.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.printf("No palindromes found in \"%s\"%n", str);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" palindromes found in \"%s\"%n", palindromes, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
No palindromes found in "null"
No palindromes found in ""
No palindromes found in "None"
"[Madam, Arora, malayalam]" palindromes found in "Madam Arora teaches malayalam"
"[Nitin, malayalam]" palindromes found in "Nitin speaks malayalam"
```